# Changing the way to code the Query to solve Missing Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know whether there is an alternative way to code the query below in order for me to solve Missing Index issue as attached in the picture.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE rsm_status = 'R' 
  AND orderid IN (SELECT mob_order_id_fk 
                  FROM DBName..TableB 
                  WHERE mob_ProcessStatus = 'C')
```

I tried to use `INNER JOIN` but the missing index issue is still there. I am prohibited from creating an Index and the only way given to me is to change the way I code the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN DBName..TableB ON orderid = mob_order_id_fk
WHERE rsm_status = 'R' 
  AND orderid IN (SELECT mob_order_id_fk 
                  FROM DBName..TableB 
                  WHERE mob_ProcessStatus = 'C')
```

[image]

[Here is the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkmLL4Evj)

Any help will really be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `select * from` is a smell here. Selecting only the columns you really need may help you to use existing indexes (and in any cases should perform and maintain better as a rule).

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Pretty unlikely given your main `where` clause column is `rsm_status`. The real question is, does it cause a performance issue? If not don't worry about it.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I am unable to upload it as a file in the Paste The Plan website. Do you mean you need this? USE [dai_production]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[RollSheetMain] ([rsm_status])
INCLUDE ([rsm_desc],[rsm_dept],[rsm_BalanceRoll],[rsm_CreatedTimeStamp],[rsm_planner_remarks],[rsm_Planner_Keep],[rsm_planner_remarks_timestamp])
GO

Comment: @topsail: i am not sure what is the required columns as i am just tasked to maintain the database and improve the performance of the execution time. but i agree with you to only select the columns that are needed.

Comment: Pretty hard to carry out your task if you don't know the required columns?

Comment: @DaleK : I think it does affect the performance somehow. This is what I get when I checked through SET STATISTICS TIME ON . SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 687 ms,  elapsed time = 871 ms.

Comment: If you can't upload the plan, post the `CREATE TABLE` statements, including indexes.

Comment: Oh it will of course have an effect on performance, but is it a bad effect. And seriously, if you are tasked with improving performance but cannot suggest new indexes, you are pretty stuck.

Comment: You have a bunch of index scan operations going on. Fixing that will require you to stop using `SELECT *` (and only list the columns actually needed from the query) and / or index tuning. That's about it.

Comment: My subjective opinion is that I am not at all concerned with the requested new index for RollSheetMain. It already has an index and I would not expect the estimated 5k rows to be your bottleneck. What I would be focusing on are the table scans on ProductionScheduleDetails (800k rows) and ProductionRecord_LAM (180k rows).  Because much of the query is encapsulated in the view definition, it is hard to see what can be done to improve the plan. Of the limiting conditions, which limits the most? ...

Comment: ... If by chance the order_id condition is most limiting, I would try rewriting your query to put the `SELECT mob_order_id_fk FROM Planning..MasterOrderProcess_BAG WHERE mob_ProcessStatus = 'C'` up front as a subselect and then join to the vRetrieveRollSheetMain_LAM_All view using either a INNER LOOP JOIN or FORCE ORDER option to try to limit the data retrieved from the view. Not a guaranteed approach, but is worth a try. (Note of caution: by forcing plan hints, this disables aspects of the query optimizer. It is a tradeoff.)

Comment: @TN: your were correct. I changed the query into this: SELECT mob_order_id_fk
 FROM
 Planning..MasterOrderProcess_BAG 
 INNER JOIN dai_production..vRetrieveRollSheetMain_LAM_All
 ON mob_order_id_fk = orderid
 WHERE mob_ProcessStatus = 'C' AND rsm_status = 'R' . No Missing Index Issue until I added dai_production..vRetrieveRollSheetMain_LAM_All.* as columns to be selected. I think the issue is from the vRetrieveRollSheetMain_LAM_All table itself. However, I am clueless on what columns can I select from that table as my superior wouldn't tell me. Anyways, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @NazAzhar "*However, I am clueless on what columns can I select from that table as my superior wouldn't tell me.*" - *I went to a car mechanic and told him my car won't start. But I didn't let him look at my car and he isn't allowed to make repairs to it. How can he get it to start?* If you're tasked with needing to improve performance but you're not provided the ability to do so (index tuning) and aren't allowed to know the details (the specific columns used in the query), then it's near impossible to do your task. You should let your superior know this, and if they disagree, I'd change jobs.

Comment: @NazAzhar - please note that comments are *not for conversations* - this isn't a discussion board. This question now has over a dozen comments, and several comments contain more details of your question. Please move all of these details to your question and delete the comments - as written, it's *very* difficult to understand the full question, given how spread out it is. Also, in comments, all of your code (which includes queries) is unformatted, making it hard to read (which is why it needs to be in your question, properly formatted)